# Unable to access the SharePoint Url

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I'm unable to access the SharePoint Url with the site name `http://hhhhhhhhh/sites/example`, but when I use the IP address like this `http://10.44.38.43/sites/rover` - I'm can get into the page.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have DNS records in place pointing `http://hhhhhh/sites/example` to the IP of your server? That's the first thing to check

Comment: Or you might have missed the bindings in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

You should check in SharePoint (if 2013) Central Administration -> System Settings -> Farm Management -> Configure alternate access mappings if you have added your server address: http://hhhhhhhhh

If not, you should add it.
Here you can see how it should look:
http://www.ivchenko.pro/SiteAssets/Lists/Posts/AllPosts/alternate-access-mappings.png

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Login to SharePoint server, check if the site is browsing with site name i.e **http://hhhhhhhhh/sites/example** on the server (you may have to add a host entry  for hhhhhhhhhh in your host file.).

If the site is browsing fine there, then its most probably a DNS level issue not the SharePoint one. Apparently it looks like your DNS is not resolving the web address and when you type the IP manually, it works.